# Install web2py on domain hosting

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

How can I deploy or install web2py on domain hosting?

Each time i try to run the command `python web2py.py`, I get:

> please visit:
>           http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   use "kill -SIGTERM 38820" to shutdown the web2py server
>
> ERROR:Rocket.Errors.Port8000:Socket 127.0.0.1:8000 in use by other process and it won't share.
>   WARNING:Rocket.Errors.Port8000:Listener started when not ready.

Even when I change the ports, I still get the same error.